# EPPlus - ExcelWorksheets Class "Add(string Name)" Method trims the worksheet name

Tags: epplus

I am using EpPlus (version 3.1.3.0) and observed that, when I add a new worksheet to workbook with a name of 35 char, it trims the name to 31 char.

Do we have any newer version of EPPlus with the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an apparently un(der)-documented limitation of Excel, not EPPlus (or even OOXML's SpreadsheetML, based on what I've gleaned from ECMA-376).

See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681908/402749).