# Will Excel run out of table names ever?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that first deletes any tables that are in the workbook and creates new tables in excel in a loop and right now  it is making about 1000s of them at once Currently I  have the following table no.`Table59860171` as the name of a table.

> Question is will excel at any point run out of unique names for a table ?

This question arose because I'll be running this same process again and again so can this be a problem ?

If yes how can I avoid it ?

Comment: When you say "Table" do you mean "Worksheet" or ["Excel table"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)?

Comment: Excel Table ofcourse

Comment: My apologies. Ignore my answer then.

Comment: The max size of table name is 255. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681868/is-there-a-limit-on-an-excel-worksheets-name-length. That should be more than enough.

Comment: Sorry I linked the wrong article Should be this. http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/551-tips-naming-and-renaming-excel-tables. If I understand your question correctly, my original comment still valid.  If not, please ignore the comment.

Comment: So what happens when the Table Name reaches Table9999999....(20 x 9's) ?

Comment: Lets say you create 10000 tables each day of the year for 50 years.  10000*365*50 =  182500000.  Total length Table182500000 is only 14.  Don't worry, let the next generation handle the problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, Excel will run out of table names.**  As Jules notes (and can be confirmed by trying long names in Excel), Excel table names are limited to 255 characters (as of the time of writing- I'm using Excel 2010).  So, there is a finite number of table names available.

**However**, the number of possibilities is very, very high.  It is not quite every combination of letters and numbers up to a 255 character string since some combinations are not allowed, such as names that could also be a cell reference (the table name "T100" is not allowed as it could also mean cell T100).

Assuming that you continue naming tables from "Table1" to "Table*N*":
Your largest table name would be

> Table9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

If you added **100 Billion tables every second**, you could add tables for

> 1,157,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407,407
>   **days.**

According to [Sydney Observatory](http://www.sydneyobservatory.com.au/2013/will-the-earth-be-engulfed-when-the-sun-becomes-a-red-giant/), the Earth will be engulfed by the Sun long before you ever run out of table names.

---

Feel free to check my math- correct me if I've made a mistake:

> 9,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999
>   / (100,000,000,000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

Comment: "the Earth will be engulfed by the Sun long before you ever run out of table names."   Gee, what a lame excuse for bad coding practices .. :P  (heh)