# Can you set the sheet name width using XSSFworkbook?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

I am working with XSSFWorkbook and I was wonder if there is a way to set the width of the sheet name field.  The name being placed in the sheet name is 32 characters long.  The app use to use HSSFWorkbook which would cut off the last character to make it fit but xssfworkbook does not.

I have searched for an answer but could not find one so I thought I would ask here to see if anyone else may have come across this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681868/is-there-a-limit-on-an-excel-worksheets-name-length) Q/A.

Comment: Thank you Abhijith for the answer.